# PhpStorm: extract() identifying variables

Tags: php, phpstorm, extract

Does anyone know whether there is a setting in PhpStorm that can trigger identifying variables generated using `extract()` function?

Example would be something like the following:

```
/**
 * @return array
 */
protected function orderSet() : array
{
    //...

    return [
        'colour' => $colour,
        'green' => $green,
        'orange' => $orange
    ];
}


/**
 * @test
 */
public function returns_correct_attribute_names()
{
    $params = $this->orderSet();
    extract($params);

    $this->assertEquals(
        'Colour',
        $colour->name
    );
}
```

At the moment any variable that's been extracted in the test is highlighted (unrecognised), but perhaps there is a setting that can change this behaviour?

Comment: You can use inline PHPDoc comment with `@var` to tell IDE that this variable is known and what type it is: `/** @var MyClass $color */`

Comment: Thanks @LazyOne - so other than using annotation, there's nothing else in PhpStorm?

Comment: Actually, just tried that and this didn't seem to work either.

Comment: @LazyOne But what about rest variables: $green, $orange? PhpDockBlock can help to understand what variable is it, but it cannot help understand where this variable defined or how we obtain it.

Comment: @seb It works just fine: http://postimg.org/image/c2plvxkkh/

Comment: @seb *"so other than using annotation, there's nothing else in PhpStorm?"* Please describe how do you expect to detect random variable and (especialy) it's type out of plain `array` definition?

Comment: @seb Another possible approach (note usage of list and more correct return type in @return tag of `orderSet()`) -- https://postimg.org/image/h0006zwzl/

Comment: @VladimirKovpak Please share your ideas on how do you expect to detect the origin of the variable. The possible solutions: do not use `extract()` or alike and work with array elements directly; return objects instead of arrays (DTO -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object); for types -- use more precise type hints. PhpStorm performs static analysis. Surely, some more deeper analysis can possibly be implemented... but on big or messy project it will take much more time for analysis of time (which results in more memory consumption; slower editing etc)

Comment: @LazyOne Yes, nice suggestion - do not use `extract()`! There are many other options... And in this case it isn't DTO it is rather VO. And i think for such purposes value object (VO) is the best solution.

Comment: Thanks guys - appreciate your input. The issue I have is that I want to make it as short as possible in the sense that if I was to use `list()`, I would have to run it with possibly a large number of variables from within each method of the given test class - wheres using `extract()` is really short. One thing I've forgotten to mention is that the `orderSet()` method is stored with the trait, which is re-used with multiple test classes.

Comment: Using object (whatever type) would mean that I cannot use named variables - rather object with named properties, which probably is not that bad after all and I think this will be the option I'm going to go for. Thanks again.

Comment: @seb short code can be very complex, ´extract()´ may cost more for your server than VOs. Sometimes its better to waste some lines of code in benefit of having a lighter application.

Answer (score 23):

The solution that LazyOne offered actually works. However there is a bit more context you need in order to implement it.

To accurately inform PHPSTORM about the variables you want to declare the **comment** must be placed **directly above** **extract()** and not the parent function.

```
   public function db(){
    $db = new SQLite3('db/mysqlitedb.db');

    $payments = $db->query('SELECT * FROM payments');

    while ($pay = $payments->fetchArray()){
        /**
         * @var string $to_user
         * @var string $from_user
         * @var number $amount
         */
        extract($pay);
        if (isset($to_user, $from_user, $amount))
            echo "TO: {$to_user}| FROM: {$from_user}| $ {$amount} \n";
    };
}
```

This is a working sample from my code ( couldn't copy yours for some reason ).

You can see just before I use the **extract()** function I declare in the comment block above it the hidden variables and data types.

*Bonus: if you intend to use extract, I highly recommend you use an isset to ensure the array you're parsing contains the fields you are expecting.
example in code above*

Comment: Huh... After more than 10 years using PHP, TIL: isset can take more than 1 variable. +1